# transformers not found by WebStorm

Tags: dart, webstorm, dart-polymer

I have several libraries I developed with Dart Eclipse plugin I am now trying to move to WebStorm since Eclipse on Windows is no longer supported.

Each time I do a pub upgrade I get the following error:

```
Transformer library "package:initialize/build/loader_replacer.dart" not found.
```

When I attempt to run my application that have dedpendencies the output in the console is

```
J:\dart\dart-sdk\bin\pub.bat serve web --port=56900
Loading source assets...
Loading initialize/build/loader_replacer, code_transformers/src/delete_file and smoke/src/default_transformer transformers...
Transformer library "package:code_transformers/src/delete_file.dart" not found.
Pub Serve terminated
```

The Dartium browser displays

```
502 Bad Gateway

WebStorm 10.0.4
```

initialize library is to me a transient dependency. Any help is sorting this issue is welcome.

I am using the current Dart release 1.11.0 (ref 65704b3)

Comment: Finally working after running pub cache clean.

Comment: I am with some problem in Webstorm 11 (EAP)... Do you just delete ..\Pub\Cache and get dependencies again?